# Organizing imports with __init__.py

Tags: python, python-2.7, optimization, import

I'm writing some py 2.7 code and would like to optimize my imports. My project file structure looks like this:

```
.
├── example.py
├── __init__.py
├── libs
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── scraper.py
│   ├── vulnlookup.py
│   └── vulnlookup.pyc
└── py-wordstress.py
```

contents of both `__init__.py` files.

```
import requests
```

When I try to create an object from the `requests` module in another file like `example.py`, I cannot access the methods like the module hasn't been imported. Maybe I'm totally wrong on this, but isn't there a way to only import your common libraries once inside of `__init__.py` and use them across your project?

Essentially my main goal is to optimize imports so that I'm not doing an `import requests` in every single python file I create.

Answer (score 3):

the `__init__.py` file doesn't work that way. You need to import all requirements in the file where they are needed. So in your case, you will need to `import requests` in example.py and any other file that uses requests.

You can use `__init__.py` to have a cleaner import for your packages.

So in your libs library, you can setup `__init__.py` to look like this:

```
from .scraper import MyScraper
from .vulnlookup import MyFunction
```

Then if you use need to use your libs somewhere else, you can simplify the imports like this:

```
from .libs import MyScrapper
#instead of: 
#from .libs.scraper import MyScraper
```